# How can discontinuous functions like $\tan(x)$ be integrated?

Tags: integration

According to the definition of integration, we are allowed to integrate only continuous functions.

We know than $\tan(x)$ is not continuous at $x=n\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}$.

But we know that $\int\tan(x)=-\log(\sec(x))$.

So suppose if we integrate between $0$ and $3\pi$, then $\tan(x)$ will not be continuous at all points.  So why do we integrate $\tan(x)$ if it is against the rules of integration?

Comment: That is not true. Integrable functions on $[a,b]$ is a separate class than continuous function on $[a,b]$

Comment: I didn't get it

Comment: according to *"what* definition of integration? For most, there are many discontinuous functions on the interval $[a,b]$ that are integrable

Comment: I dint know which definition in my book it is written that if phi(x) is a continues function then there exist a function f(x) such that f'(x) =phi(x)

Comment: Why down vote??

Comment: It should also be noted that tangent is discontinuous at ODD multiples of $\pi / 2$ not what is originally stated. Just minor detail

Comment: @ATHARVA: The "if"-statement in your book is true (on an interval!), but you're reading it as "if and only if", which is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous on $[a_1,a_2)$ with $a_1<a_2$ we can integrate $f$ on $[a_1,c]$ for any $c\in [a_1,a_2).$ And  we define $$\int_{a_1}^{a_2}f(x)\;dx\lim_{c\to (a_2)^-}\int_{a_1}^c f(x)\;dx$$ provided that this limit exists. The notation $c\to (a_2)^-$ means that $c$ approaches $a_2$ thru values less than $a_2.$ Similarly if $f$ is continuous on $(a_1,a_2]$ we define $$\int_{a_1}^{a_2}f(x)=\lim_{c\to (a_1)^+}\int_c^{a_2}f(x)\;dx$$  provided this limit exists.

In your example we cannot define a real number $\int_0^{3\pi} \tan x\; dx$ even if we break the interval $[0,3\pi]$ into (finitely  or infinitely many) sub-intervals $[a_1,a_2], [a_2,a_3],...$ because $\int_0^c \tan x\;dx$ tends to $\infty$ as $c\to (\pi/2)^-.$

Modern integration theory encompasses a much broader class than continuous functions, broader than functions  with the occasional discontinuity. This was not just for mathematical creativity but for practical applications in science.

Comment: So you want to say that we cannot integrate tan x between 0 and 3pi

Comment: So you mean to say we cannot integrate tan x in the interval[0,3pi].

Comment: Not over the whole interval.

Comment: So can we do it by breaking it to intervals [0,pi/2],[pi/2,3pi/2],[3pi/2,5pi/2],[5pi/2,3pi] and then add them.

Comment: No. We can't have an odd multiple of $\pi /2$ as an end-point of a sub-interval or we get $\pm \infty$ when we integrate.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that integration is only possible for continuous functions. There is a whole class of definite integrals where the integrand is discontinuous somewhere in the interval of integration, such an integral is called an [improper integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral).

Furthermore, in the case of $\int \tan x \ dx = -\ln(\cos x) +C$, this is because $ -\ln(\cos x)$ is the antiderivtive of $\tan x$, in the sense that ${d \over dx} \left(-\ln(\cos x)\right) = \tan x$, which is a topic separate from a definite integral.